# How to close Progress dialog from background

Tags: android, background-process, progressdialog

I am kinda new to android and stuck in a situation, where I don't know how to handle it.

Here is what I am trying to do:

From Activity I start some tasks and show Progress-Dialog  while the task completes in background.
If the task successfully completes I close the Activity and start new Activity.

But if in background I caught an exception I want to go back to the activity and close the Progress-Dialog and show a Toast maybe that some exception has occurred.

From Activity:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
{
 // my code

 // start Progress Dialog
   showProgressDialog();  
}

public void showProgressDialog()
{
   PD =  new ProgressDialog(getActivity());
   PD.setMessage("Downloading.....");
   PD.show();
}

@Override
public void onDestroy()
{
   super.onDestroy();
   if (PD != null) 
   {
      PD.dismiss();
      PD = null;
   }
}
```

and in background:

```
try 
{
   // perform some db tasks 
   // using AsyncTask 
}
catch (Exception e) 
{
   if(e.getErrorCode() == 34)
   {
      // From here I want go back to Activity and close the Progress dialog
      // and shows what error has occurred.
   }
}
```

So if exception occurred how I am suppose to go back to the activity and close that Progress-dialog, or is there any other way to doing this?

Comment: A better approach would be to use an Async task and its methods are well suited for your problem situation. You can check your results in onPostExecute and based on them you can start an intent

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I know ProgressDialog is in your UI thread and you don't access to that in the background thread. Why don't you use AsyncTask instead ? It's easy to use and you can handle it much easier. Example:

```
class TestAsync extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

        private ProgressDialog mDialog;
        private Boolean error = false;

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {

            mDialog = new ProgressDialog(TestActivity.this);
            mDialog.setCancelable(false);
            mDialog.show();

        }

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... arg0) {


            try {
                // whatever you would like to do in background
            } catch (Exception e) {
                error = true;
            }

            return null;
        }

        protected void onPostExecute(Void... arg0) {
            mDialog.dismiss();

            if (error) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                        R.string.error, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                return;
            } else {

                // whatever you would like to do after background 
            } 

        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

assuming that the `AsyncTask`  is an inner class of the Activity where you declared the ProgressDialog, you can simply return, and dismiss the it in onPostExecute that runs on the UI Thread:

Assuming your asynctask returns a String

```
catch (Exception e) 
{
   if(e.getErrorCode() == 34)
   {
      // From here I want go back to Activity and close the Progress dialog
      // and shows what error has occurred.
      return "34"
   }
}



public void onPostExecute(String result) {
    // dismiss
    // show result
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If task is taking long time you should not run it on UI tread. You should use Async task.

Also you should always check if dialog ref still exists.

```
if(dialog!=null && dialog.isShowing())
  dialog.dismiss();
```

make sure Async task is run on same class else use listeners with weakreference to post response of the task.